# Does maple provide function to calculate drift and stochastic terms for Levy process

Tags: maple

I find maple provide Drift() and Diffusion() functions for Ito's process. Does it provide similar function for Levy process?

I want to expand my specific function f(t,N(t)) with Levy processs by Ito's lemma in maple? N(t) is a compound Poisson process. Is there any example to do that?